# Cannot drop/alter tables due to transaction ended in trigger error ms-sql-server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I cannot alter/drop any objects in my database, only create, insert, and delete records. For instance, I'm getting...

You can not
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

on the following code (on the drop table step):

```
create schema Test
go
create table test.test (
test varchar(5) 
)
go
insert into test.test(test) values('test')
go
select *
from Test.test
go
drop table Test.test
go
drop schema Test
go
```

I have definitely not created any triggers on the database EVER. I do not have control of the server so my permissions are limited. The problem just occurred. I have been using this database for years. This is the first time this has happened. I believe it has something to do with permissions.

I have no idea what is causing this new error to occur.

Comment: Code seems fine...something is missing. Can you execute each `GO` block and see if it executes smoothly ?

Comment: Everything works fine up to the "drop" statement, which is when I get the error. I can't drop it or alter the design. I can create the table and then only add/delete records.

Comment: No problems on my local computer, but that's as expected. I have to think this has something to do with the way my remote account is configured. The techs hosting the site are also unable to drop the table using their sa account.

Comment: I found the problem. Someone hacked my database by adding a database trigger "test_ddl_trigger":     SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    create trigger [test_ddl_trigger] on database for drop_table, alter_table 
    as print 'You can not' 
    rollback
    ;

    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    GO

    ENABLE TRIGGER [test_ddl_trigger] ON DATABASE
    GO

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Someone hacked my database by adding a database trigger "test_ddl_trigger":

```
`SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
create trigger [test_ddl_trigger] on database for drop_table, alter_table as print 'You can not' 
rollback 
; 
GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO 
ENABLE TRIGGER [test_ddl_trigger] ON DATABASE 
GO`
```